# How to replace nodemon in a way that accommodates --inspect=9230

Tags: node.js, apollo, graphql-js, npm-scripts

I have an npm script that starts apollo graphql and works as such:

```
"dev":"dotenv -e \"../.env.${SOME_ENV_VAR}\" nodemon --config nodemon.dev.json ./src/main.ts
```

I now want to slightly change it with the equivalent of the node `--inspect=9230` parameter.

How would I rewrite this script to effectively do the same thing but allow debugging on port 9230 (not the default port of 9229)?

Additionally, even better if I can add the concept of graphql schema file auto reload like:

```
"debug": "concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"npm run watchgraphql\" \"nodemon --inspect build/dist/index.js\"",
"watchgraphql": "cpx 'src/graphql/schemas/**/*.graphql' build/dist/graphql/schemas/ -w -v"
```

I would normally just use the above graphql sample script but it lacks the `dotenv -e \"../.env.${SOME_ENV_VAR}\"` part from my originally stated goal.
Whatever I have done, I have not been able to infuse the concept of `dotenv -e \"../.env.${SOME_ENV_VAR}\"` in to the graphql script example... The command and parameter parsing gets all messed up and nothing executes properly.

```
nodemon.dev.json:
{
  "watch": [
    "src"
  ],
  "ext": "ts,gql",
  "ignore": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/types/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "register": [
    "graphql-import-node/register"
  ],
  "execMap": {
    "ts": "ts-node"
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: To run ts + node-inspect with nodemon update your execMap as such: `"ts": "node -r ts-node/register --inspect PORT"`. Think that's what our config looks like. If it doesn't work I can check once I'm at a PC :)

Comment: Could you please kindly give me some feedback about my answer?

Comment: @DanieleRicci - Your answer is something I had tried and it doesn't work because the parameters get all wonky and do not get properly passed.  I ended up solving it with MarcRo's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Directly from [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon)'s README.

> You can also pass the inspect flag to node through the command line as you would normally:

```
nodemon --inspect ./server.js 80
```

it should be enough:

```
"dev": "dotenv -e \"../.env.${SOME_ENV_VAR}\" nodemon --config nodemon.dev.json --inspect=9230 ./src/main.ts"
```